# AlarmReceiver never receives a call from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm within the Fragment.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 23);

manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 3600, pendingIntent);
```

And my AlarmReceiver class is:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive");
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This log and toast are never shown.

In my AndroidManifest i have put

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></receiver>
```

Am I missing something? This is my first project in Android so its probably some rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example which is working TESTED:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 3600, pendingIntent);
```

If it doesn't work I can send you the working project I made.

Answer (score 1):

You're using PendingIntent.getService(...), rather than the BroadcastReceiver equivalent, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...).  Which is likely the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help i replaced `PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);` with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);` and i still have nothing.

Comment: Might be something to do with your setRepeating call as well, did you try lessening the delay time frame to make it fire more frequently while testing?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that if you set the alarm once (like on App first launch) and while waiting you make some changes in the code and install the App again your pending intent not active anymore, so you need to set the alarm again.